# google sheets: compare two columns and output matched keys

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to generate a list of project keys that relate to relevant projects, that I retrieve from a query including different conditions (for simplicity I've added the queried list of relevant projects in A2:A5). The goal is to generate the output in A11, i.e., get all project keys related to the queried projects (excluding the current project) that are assigned the same client.

I have the following spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nIkpVMf8PurJVB96EE-kOltUqhwFHOydi2uvuJq2yMU/edit?usp=sharing
[image]

My current solution produces only a list of projects, but not the keys.

```
Query({A2:A5}, select"Col1 where Col1 matches '"& textjoin("|",True,query({C2:E6},"select Col1 where Col3=1"))&"'",0)
```

Any ideas how to solve this? NO arreyformula etc. since I don't actually "print" the queried projects anywhere.

Comment: Does it have to be a native spreadsheet formula *(1)* or could it also be an App Script script *(2)*? You could also create your own formula that does exactly what you want in Apps Script and then use that in your sheet just like any other formula *(3)*. Which of the three options is acceptable for you? The best option to my mind would probably be *(3)*.

Comment: @Mushroomator native formula, no App Script please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=textjoin(",",,arrayformula(vlookup(Query({A2:A5}, "select Col1 where Col1 matches '"& textjoin("|",True,query({C2:E6},"select Col1 where Col3=1"))&"'",0),C2:E6,2,0)))
```

=> A12, B34, D78

or, to exclude current project

```
=textjoin(",",,arrayformula(vlookup(Query({A2:A5}, "select Col1 where Col1<>'"&A8&"' and Col1 matches '"& textjoin("|",True,query({C2:E6},"select Col1 where Col3=1"))&"'",0),C2:E6,2,0)))
```

=> B34, D78

Comment: That's the perfect solution, thanks a lot!